# jetty runner plugin for IntelliJ Idea install error

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I'm using Intellij Idea 2022.2.3, while I wanna use jetty runner, the lastest jetty version is 1.4.20, and I got an error as below:

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: The default implementation of method 'getId' is deprecated, you need to override it in 'class com.github.guikeller.jettyrunner.conf.JettyRunnerConfigurationFactory'. The default implementation delegates to 'getName' which may be localized, but return value of this method must not depend on current localization. [Plugin: JettyRunner-GK]
at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginProblemReporterImpl.createPluginExceptionByClass(PluginProblemReporterImpl.java:23)
at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.createByClass(PluginException.java:83)
at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException.reportDeprecatedDefault(PluginException.java:110)
at com.intellij.execution.configurations.ConfigurationFactory.getId(ConfigurationFactory.java:75)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.writeExternal(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.kt:265)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.writeScheme(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.kt:321)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.LazySchemeProcessor.writeScheme(scheme-impl.kt:65)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurationSchemeManager.writeScheme(RunConfigurationSchemeManager.kt:121)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurationSchemeManager.writeScheme(RunConfigurationSchemeManager.kt:21)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.schemeManager.SchemeManagerImpl.saveScheme(SchemeManagerImpl.kt:393)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.schemeManager.SchemeManagerImpl.save(SchemeManagerImpl.kt:333)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.Scheme_implKt.save(scheme-impl.kt:164)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.getState(RunManagerImpl.kt:643)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.getState(RunManagerImpl.kt:78)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:334)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:240)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.commitComponents$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:94)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl$commitComponentsOnEdt$$inlined$withEdtContext$intellij_platform_configurationStore_impl$1.invokeSuspend(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:723)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.constraints.BaseConstrainedExecution$Companion$scheduleWithinConstraints$1.invoke(BaseConstrainedExecution.kt:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.constraints.BaseConstrainedExecution$Companion.scheduleWithinConstraints(BaseConstrainedExecution.kt:71)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.constraints.BaseConstrainedExecution.scheduleWithinConstraints(BaseConstrainedExecution.kt:38)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl.access$scheduleWithinConstraints$s1153900543(BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl.kt:12)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl$scheduleWithinConstraints$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:513)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:75)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:118)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:42)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:779)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:749)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:918)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:766)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:791)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:624)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that plugin is out of date with your version of Intellij.  It seems like the plugin has not been updated recently and is looking for a new maintainer.

You could

- fork it and make the changes suggested in the error message (it doesn't seem like it would be too complicated)
- Downgrade your intellij - probably a bad idea, but if you are really in a pinch might be the fastest way to get past this
- Find an alternate solution; perhaps use the [jetty maven plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin) which appears to be still supported and has easy commands to run jetty (which can be put into an intellij run configuration)

I would recommend the last way.  If you are already using maven, it will be pretty easy. If you are not using maven then it is a good opportunity to learn how to use it as it is very helpful for managing java projects

Answer (score 0):

Although I am looking for a new maintainer I still am maintaining the plugin.
Please raise an issue on GitHub so this can be fixed, cheers!
Project link: https://github.com/guikeller/jetty-runner

PS: raised an issue on your behalf:
https://github.com/guikeller/jetty-runner/issues/81